Creating Nested List with Google Sheet Formulas from Pre-Made Tables
I need a dynamic nested list based on items and subitems.
For example, if I have a list of items



A
B




1
Item 1


2
Item 2


3
Item 3



And a list of subitems



C
D




Subitem 1
Item 1


Subitem 2
Item 1


Subitem 3
Item 2


Subitem 4
Item 3


Subitem 5
Item 3



My result should be:



E




Item 1


Subitem 1


Subitem 2


Item 2


Subitem 3


Item 3


Subitem 4


Subitem 5



So far, the only idea that I could came up with was
=TRANSPOSE(
   SPLIT(JOIN(";", 
      MAP(
         UNIQUE(FILTER($B2:$B,$B2:$B<>"")), LAMBDA(x, FLATTEN(x & ";" & JOIN(";",IFERROR(FILTER($C2:$C,$D2:$D=x),)))))
   ),";")
)

But I wonder if there is a better way of doing this. Any ideas?

You can use REDUCE. Enter the following formula in E1:
=REDUCE("E",TOCOL(B2:B,1),LAMBDA(a,c,{a;c;FILTER(C:C,D:D=c)})) 

If you don't want the header, use:
=REDUCE(TOCOL(,1),TOCOL(B2:B,1),LAMBDA(a,c,{a;c;FILTER(C:C,D:D=c)})) 


Works great, thanks! In case I can't have the "E" on the first row, any tweaks that can be done?

For this particular case, you may try-
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(C1:D,2,1),1))



Thanks! The only problem with this method is that if I have subitems with the sabe name in different items, they will show up only once. But if all subitems are named differently, this is also great
